# How to get a Provider<MyBloc>.of(context) inside my ModalRoute

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I'm trying to access a BloC inside a Widget nested with a ModalRoute.

Here is the MultiProvider and It's working fine because I can access inside the HomeTab.

```
 child: MultiProvider(
            providers: [
              StreamProvider<User>(create: (_) => _userBloc.userStream),
            ],
            child: Consumer<User>(
              builder: (context, value, child) => Scaffold(
                body: TabBarView(
                  controller: _tabController,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.orange,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    HomeTab(), // Here is the nested Widget, I can access inside it. 
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.pink,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

Here is the HomeTab with my Modal handler.

```
class HomeTab extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeTab({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  void _showOverlay(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(UserProfileModal()); // here I call the Modal and I'm passing the context.
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    User _user = Provider.of<User>(context); // Here It's ok! I can access!
```

The problem is here, inside the ModalRoute

```
class UserProfileModal extends ModalUI {
  UserProfileModal();

  @override
  Widget buildPage(
    BuildContext context,
    Animation<double> animation,
    Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
  ) {
    User _user = Provider.of<User>(context); // Here I can't access
```

The error log:

Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Builder Widget

This likely happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice.

Can anyone clarify this doubt? Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
  Provider<User>.value(
    value: Provider.of<User>(context, listen: false),
    child: UserProfileModal()
  )
);
```